# Unparseable date exception in Android API 25 but not 22 or 23

Tags: java, android, android-7.1-nougat

I have been developing my app and testing with emulators and devices with `Api 22 and 23` but when I tested on a device with `API 25` or `Version 7.1 Nougat` today I am suddenly experiencing the following Exception:

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-02-08 18:39:21+00"
W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:358)
```

I am parsing the date `"2017-02-08 18:39:21+00"` using the following pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"` and this has been working fine until I tested in an emulator running `API 25` and I also tried it on a `Nexus 6P` running the same version and I get the same exception.

The following method is where the exception occurs on `API 25`. It works fine on the other versions I am testing on.

```
private static final String SERVER_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ";

public static Date javaDateFromStringDate(String stringDate) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(SERVER_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
    return format.parse(stringDate);
}
```

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you should be using `X`, not `Z`, for a two-digit time zone value.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare but I still get the exception even with the `X`

Comment: The release notes for Nougat say it can better match device Locale and app Locale. Don't use Locale.getDefault() for parsing. Use Locale.US or a locale you are 100% confident for

Comment: @carlpoole Seems 'Z' expects 5digits(`Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes`) when the input is  changed from `+00` to `+0000` it works. And also instead of 'Z' if you use 'X' it works. Tested in Android(7.1.1) emulator.

Comment: @blizzard thank you... I went back and re-tried this and it seems like this in fact is the issue. For some reason on API 25 it is stricter about enforcing the difference between 2 and 4 digit timezones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers was indeed to use `X` for two-digit timezones per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Thanks to @commonsware and @blizzard in the comments. It appears Android didn't seem to mind if you used `Z` for two-digit timezones but got stricter about it in `Nougat`.